# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В итоге если раньше на изготовление и наладку литой заготовки требовалось 16 часов, то теперь (,) на специальном обрабатывающем центре итальянского производства, который заменяет 10 станков, — максимум два часа.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы, Аленка, после "теперь" идет уточняющее обстоятельство времени, поэтому запятая нужна

Comment: Мне кажется, там идет обстоятельство места: на специальном обрабатывающем центре итальянского производства, который заменяет 10 станков.

Comment: Обстоятельства, разумеется, разные, но в данном случае происходит сближение значений по времени: теперь, когда используется новое оборудование. И всё предложение построено так, чтобы выделить фактор времени на первый план. А во втором примере такого сближения нет, там противопоставляется старое и новое оборудование, поэтому нет и обособления.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, так как  по структуре предложения оборот уточняет  местоимение "теперь" (раньше - теперь, а когда именно). Стоит обратить внимание на расстановку ударений:

В итоге если рАньше на изготовление и наладку литой заготовки требовалось 16 часов, то тепЕрь, на специальном обрабатывающем центре итальянского производства, который заменяет 10 станков, — максимум два часа.

В похожем по смыслу предложении обособления нет, здесь логически выделены слова "старом - новом".

В итоге если на стАром оборудовании на изготовление и наладку литой заготовки требовалось 16 часов, то теперь  на нОвом станке это максимум два часа.

Comment: Теперь - это наречие,а не местоимение

Comment: Может быть, местоименное наречие?